# Como filtrar itens no field foreign key do form django?

Tags: html, python, django

Boa noite! Sou novo em python/djagno, e também sou novo aqui na comunidade, inclusive, essa é minha primeira pergunta.

O que eu quero fazer é filtrar os itens de uma lista de seleção de uma foreign key (Modelo) na tela de cadastro de placas.

Ex.: Mostrar na lista apenas o que estiver como True na coluna Ativo da tabela Modelo_placas

## cadastro_placas.py (models)

```
class Cadastro_placas(models.Model):
Numero_serie = models.CharField(
    'Número de série',
    max_length=120
)

Modelo = models.ForeignKey(
    'placas.modelo_placas', 
    related_name='modelo_placas_modelo',
    on_delete = models.PROTECT,
    null = True,
)

Revisao_lm = models.IntegerField(
    'Revisao LM'
)

Lote_numero = models.ForeignKey(
    'placas.cadastro_lote',
    related_name='numero_lote',
    on_delete = models.PROTECT
)

Observacao = models.TextField(
    'Observação',
    blank=True
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Numero_serie

class Meta:
    db_table = 'CADASTRO_PLACAS'
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['Numero_serie'], name="Constraint_placas")
    ]
```

## modelo_placas (models)

```
class Modelo_placas(models.Model):
Modelo = models.CharField(
    'modelo',
    max_length=120
)

Descricao = models.CharField(
    'Descrição',
    max_length=200
)

Ativo = models.BooleanField(
    'Modelo Ativo',
    default=True
)



def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.Modelo, self.Descricao) 

class Meta:
    db_table = 'MODELO_PLACAS'
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['Modelo', 'Descricao'], name="Constraint_modelo")
    ]
```

## cadastrar_placa (views)

```
def cadastrar_placa(request):
context = {
    "form": PlacaForm       
}
if request.method == "POST":
    form = PlacaForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()      
return render(request, "placas/cadastrar-placa.html", context)
```

## forms.py (form)

```
class ModeloForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Modelo_placas
    fields = '__all__'

class PlacaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cadastro_placas
        fields = '__all__'
```

## cadastrar-placa.html (html)

```
                    <form method="POST" class="post-form ">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 mb-xl-1">
                            {{ form.Numero_serie  | as_crispy_field:"bootstrap"}}
                            {{ form.Revisao_lm | as_crispy_field:"bootstrap" }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 mb-xl-1">
                            {{ form.Lote_numero  | as_crispy_field:"bootstrap"}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-1 mb-xl-0 ">
                            <a href="#"><img src="{% static 'placas/images/acrescer-png.png' %}" alt="+ lote"
                                    width=15 height=15 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loteModal"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 mb-xl-4">
                            {{ form.Modelo | as_crispy_field:"bootstrap"}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 mb-xl-4">
                            {{ form.Observacao | as_crispy_field:"bootstrap"}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-outline-primary col-md-8 mb-3  ">Salvar</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema, colocando o atributo limit_choices_to no campo modelo da tabela Cadastro_placas, deixando o campo conforme código abaixo:

```
class Cadastro_placas(models.Model):   
Modelo = models.ForeignKey(
    'placas.modelo_placas', 
    related_name='modelo_placas_modelo',
    on_delete = models.PROTECT,
    null = True,
    limit_choices_to= {'Ativo': True} #Limita somente a modelos ativos
)
```

Com isso consegui com que apareça somente os modelos que estão classificados True no campo Ativo.

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode chamar o filter em Modelo_placas para pegar a lista de placas ativas e depois um for para buscar os respectivos cadastros

```
from .models import Modelo_placas, Cadastro_placas

def list_placas():
    modelos_ativos = Modelo_placas.filter(ativo=True) #retorna uma lista com as ocorrencias

    placas_ativas = []
    for modelo in modelos_ativos:
        placas_ativas.append(Cadastro_placas.objects.get(Modelo=modelo))
    data = {
        "placas":placas_ativas 
         }
    return render(request,'listaplacas', data)
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi de sua resposta, isso eu faria na view, mas como eu coloco este retorno para o campo Modelo que esta na tabela de cadastro_placa.py? Pois é neste campo que eu quero que apareça somente os modelos ativos.

Comment: Até onde sei, o  registro da ForeignKey não tem esse tipo de validação. Uma vez que vc referencie uma tabela, a principio todos items dessa tabela poderão ser cadastrados. O que pode ser feito e o controle no seu frontend, sendo feito essa validação antes de realizar o submit. Vc pode tb na própria função da view fazer essa validação antes de realizar o save. uma ultima solução, q acho não mt boa, é fezer uma tabela somente com as ativas. Nesse caso , ela teria apenas um campo que seria justamente a ForeignKey de Modelo_placas e em Cadastro_placas receberia a ForeignKey dessa tabela auxiliar